# logstash, grok - how match optional field after multiline data?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I use logstash to parse messages from filebeat.
Individual messages have the following syntax:

```
key1: some data!....
-...data continues..special symbols ..:!?111--
whatever...1234!"..??..data..continues !!';;; blabla
key2: important data
```

`key1`'s value is a multiline mess which I want to ingore.
Also note, that key2 is optional, and it can happen to not to be in the log message!

I want to parse key2 value, if present, and tried it as so:

```
key1: (?m)%{DATA}(\nkey2:%{DATA:value})?
```

, but it seems that the first `DATA` block just matches the whole message and the optional part is skipped.
I need the first `DATA` block to not to be greedy, and so not to skip `key2`.
Thanks for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this by any chance stacktrace which is intented? Then you can filter for spaces.
An example of your log might be of help.

Comment: Hey, problem is that those data contain private informations and cannot be published. I believe that what I provided as an example is pretty much enough to solve the parsing issue.

Comment: To mention, the format is actually a windows log, but I haven't found any predefined grok type for it.